# decoding a compressed binary blob using zlib

Tags: c, encoding, zlib

I have an application that seems to encode some data (a long text) as a compressed binary blob using zlib.

I would like to know how I can possibly decode the compressed binary blob.

I guess I can use the zlib library itself or a command line tool but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you want to uncompress a file with a command-line program, or do you want to uncompress the file in your own program? Both are possible, but only one of those problems could be asked about here.

Comment: you can download zlib library and uncompress it, just like that

Comment: Ok, I guess I asked is a silly question since the response is quite obvious. I'll write a simple C program that use the "inflate" function from the zlib library to try to decompress the binary blob. I guess this is *the* most obvious thing to do. I did ask the question because at the beginning I thought there was some subtleties involved like adding an header at the beginning of the blob or not.

Comment: I'm also wandering if there are different flavors of zlib that I should try. The application that produce the blob works on windows and use a shared library called zlib1.dll.